# Show both menu icon and back button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add both back button and hamburger icon in my flutter app? This is useful especially in iOS faster navigation to root pages in deep navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this: (inside your `Scaffold`)

```
 appBar: AppBar(leading: Row(children:[FirstIcon(), SecondIcon(),],),
```

To open the `Drawer`, you will have to do this: (in your widget's `build` method):

```
/// create a Drawer key
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();

/// this function opens the drawer
void _openDrawer()=>_drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();

/// then use it to open the Drawer
Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(leading: Row(children: <Widget>[IconButton(onPressed:_openDrawer, icon:Icon(Icons.hamburger,),), SecondIcon(),],),
),);
```

Edit:
Don't forget to add the `_drawerKey` to your `Drawer`. Like this:
`Drawer(key: _drawerKey, child: YourWidget(),),`

Comment: that's fine. but how do retain the function for the hamburger icon?

Comment: I get this error: The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()

Comment: Did you create the `_drawerKey` and restart your app?

Comment: this was the way I called my drawer initially:

  drawer: Drawer(
          child: NavDrawer(),
        ),

my side bar is actually a widget

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to tell you to add the `_drawerKey` to your `Drawer`... My fault, you have to set the `Drawer`'s `key` property to `_drawerKey`. Like this: `Drawer(key: _drawerKey, child: YourWidget(), ),`

Comment: thanks. this works but the icon comes after the hamburger icon not before. can I place the back button before?

Comment: Just put it before the hamburger icon in the `<Children>[]`. Like this: `<Children>[BackButton(), HamburgerButton(),],`. If this answer helped you please mark it as correct.

Comment: the problem is that if I include the HamburgerButton to the Row widget and also use this code:

Drawer(key: _drawerKey, child: YourWidget(), ),

It gives me two hamburger icons on the appBar.

Comment: This is what your `Scaffold` should look like: ```Scaffold:         appBar: AppBar(         
        leading: Row(children:[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)), IconButton(icon:
        Icon(Icons.menu),),]),
      ),
      drawer:Drawer(key: _drawerKey),```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the hamburger button at the right of the screen using the `endDrawer` attribute:

```
Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text("...")),
endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ...);
```

[image: appbar]